# Android activity launched before Application onCreate finished, does not get launched

Tags: android

I have a specific situation on my app where in `Application` `onCreate` I perform some checks and if a condition is met, I need to launch an activity (`ActivityB`).
If that condition is not met, app behaves normally and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` activity is launched (`ActivityA`).

If the condition is not met, then the user is blocked from using the application. The user is notified of this situation with ActivityB.

The problem is that sometimes the check is too fast thus, the blocking activity is launched right after the launch activity and since application `onCreate` hasn't finished, only `ActivityA` is launched.

On app start, `ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver` is set to be triggered when `@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)` is called. When this occurs, I do this:

```
blockedState.observeForever { shouldBlock ->
    if (shouldBlock) {
        context.startActivity(ActivityB.newInstance(context))
    }
}
```

If I wrap the startActivity on a postDelay (for example 1 second) then `ActivityB` is launched.

How can I overcome this situation?

In the logs I can see this:

```
I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.mypackage.name/com.me.ActivityA} from uid 2000
I/ActivityManager: Start proc 5539:com.mypackage.name/u0a895 for pre-top-activity {com.mypackage.name/com.me.ActivityA}
I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {flg=0x14008000 cmp=com.mypackage.name/com.me.ActivityB} from uid 10895
I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {cmp=com.mypackage.name/com.me.ActivityC (has extras)} from uid 10895
2021-11-24 16:50:49.956 1886-3704/? W/ActivityTaskManager: startActivity called from finishing ActivityRecord{4546773 u0 com.mypackage.name/com.me.ActivityA t7378 f}}; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=com.mypackage.name/com.me.ActivityC (has extras) }
2021-11-24 16:50:49.961 1886-3704/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Duplicate finish request for r=ActivityRecord{4546773 u0 com.mypackage.name/com.me.ActivityA t7378 f}}
I/ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.mypackage.name/com.me.ActivityA : +2s735ms
```

Comment: "How can I overcome this situation?" -- have one activity, rather than two, where the activity determines which mode it should be in (normal or blocked) and displays the appropriate UI (e.g., via fragments or composables).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare I will look into that but I found a situation where I need to perform the same checks on other activities so probably will change my implementation to use my base activity. I will post here how did it go.